# Module Seaborn has no attribute '<any graph>'

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I am having trouble switching from ggplot2 into seaborn.  Currently using Anaconda v. 4.5.8  and Python 3.6.3

Any graph I use cannot be found.  For example I can take any code from seaborn's site and run:

```
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")

dots = sns.load_dataset("dots")

# Define a palette to ensure that colors will be
# shared across the facets
palette = dict(zip(dots.coherence.unique(),
                   sns.color_palette("rocket_r", 6)))

# Plot the lines on two facets
sns.relplot(x="time", y="firing_rate",
            hue="coherence", size="choice", col="align",
            size_order=["T1", "T2"], palette=palette,
            height=5, aspect=.75, facet_kws=dict(sharex=False),
            kind="line", legend="full", data=dots)
sns.plt.show() #this was not on site code but tried it(plt.show() as referenced by other posts)
```

Error message:

```
  File "<ipython-input-8-893759310442>", line 13, in <module>
    sns.relplot(x="time", y="firing_rate",

AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'relplot'
```

Looked at these posts( among others)

(1) AtributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'plt' - Seaborn

(2) Seaborn ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

(3) ImportError after successful pip installation

(4) Error importing Seaborn module in Python

and tried the install/uninstall methods they described ( python -m pip install seaborn,  uninstall seaborn/ reinstall - etc.)  I did this in both conda using conda and cmd using pip.

I haven't spent much time with PATHs but here are screenshots:

[image: conda]

[image: pip]

Any ideas?

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation where you got that code?

Comment: relplot => regplot ?

Comment: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/faceted_lineplot.html

Comment: I've tried boxplots/lineplots other plot names with other data, that code example was just the easiest to copy/paste

Comment: So are you saying that you can't use any seaborn plotting functions?

Comment: Well I just ran a boxplot and it worked, I think the 3 that I initially tried were all additions to 0.9.0 but just installed and still not finding.  So I think it is a PATH issue

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have found that example on the *newest* version of the seaborn module, which is `0.9`. From the ["What’s new in each version"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html) section:

> New relational plots
>
> Three completely new plotting functions have been added: relplot(),
>   scatterplot(), and lineplot()

So, you need to update your seaborn to the latest version to use these plotting functions.

Comment: What were they called beforehand?

Comment: I updated seaborn, and it still did not work. Weird.

Answer (score 33):

I had this same issue. The selected answer, is correct, you have an older version, but there were a few hangups that I ran into. Here's what happened and how I corrected it. I first tried:

```
conda update seaborn
```

which did not install seaborn 0.9.0, but rather installed a 0.8.x version. I then did

```
conda remove seaborn
conda install seaborn=0.9.0
```

which still installed an older version. I finally got it to work using pip3

```
pip3 install seaborn==0.9.0
```

Which worked properly and solved the missing plots you mentioned. As long as you do this within your conda environment, it should function as though it was a conda install.

Comment: Installing it via conda worked for me with `conda install seaborn==0.9` (note the two `=`)

Comment: On a windows machine in Anaconda prompt it also works with a single '=' (conda install seaborn=0.9) as described by @Jonathan Fry

Comment: I guess after so many months conda's repository did update it to 0.9 and hence it works there too!

Answer (score 8):

First uninstall seaborn:

```
conda remove seaborn
pip uninstall seaborn
```

Then try download and install lastest version:

```
pip3 --no-cache-dir install seaborn
```

It worked for me.