# module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'relplot'

Tags: python, seaborn, google-colaboratory

I having trouble running `relplot` function in `colab` notebook but it works fine in jupyter notebook.

Getting the following error in colab

---

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", 
>         2             col="time", # Categorical variables that will determine the faceting of the grid.
>         3             hue="smoker", # Grouping variable that will produce elements with different colors.
>         4             style="smoker", # Grouping variable that will produce elements with different styles.
>         5             size="size", # Grouping variable that will produce elements with different sizes.
>
> AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'relplot'

Comment: You're using an older version of seaborn. Try upgrading to the latest.

Answer (score 4):

You're getting this error because this is a plot available only in the newest version of Seaborn (0.9), as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51402579/module-seaborn-has-no-attribute-any-graph/51402703). Try upgrading through `pip3 install seaborn==0.9.0`. If that doesn't work, it's possible Colab isn't integrated with this version.

Answer (score 1):

Change directory to where pip3.exe is located:
for me: `cd C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts`

use **.\**
`.\pip3 install seaborn==0.9.0`